# How to set presented input control value different than actual value

Tags: angular, input, angular-material

I'm using angular material and we have input type text. The goal is to present numbers like this:

- 2 000.02
- 3 000.00
- 433 232 223.21

In short I want to present values with spaces every 3 digits but to backend I want to send same value but without spaces.

So far I add spaces using regexp to every 3 digits and on ngOnDestroy I was removing them. This component has to do it because I have a lot of services along the way. This approach does not work because first I send post, then we navigate and destroy components so I still send values with spaces.

Wondering if there is smart way to solve this. Something like separate input actual value from presentation value, mask or something.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-mask

Answer (score 0):

Instead of handling the space removal on `ngOnDestroy`, why don't you handle it in a method where you call the service? I would suggest you not to modify the original value, but to clone the original object and then modify that cloned object. That way you won't have to worry about displaying the correct format.

```
callToService() {
  let clonedObject = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.inputValue));
  // Now remove the spaces from clonedObject and send that object to the API
}
```

Like @Abdul mentioned, more friendly solution would be to use something like [ngx-mask](http://npmjs.com/package/ngx-mask).

Comment: I cant do it in service because i pass configuration to input from backend and i have no idea which input will have 'amount' textransform. The json send to backend after the process is super big. Text field component has to do it somehow. Service shouldnt know anything about the input.

Comment: I didn't say directly in service but in a method where you call the service. Can't you just do a check there which format is the input value and then do what I stated above?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is. Using [accounting](https://www.npmjs.com/package/accounting) you can make a helper:

```
export function formatNumber(value) {
    return accounting.formatMoney(value, '', 0, ' ', '.');
}

export function unformatNumber(value) {
    return accounting.unformat(value);
}
```

You can simply call format/unformat depending on what you need.

Demo:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jn5bkh?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: I created methods which are working as i expect. They add or remove spaces in correct places. I want to somehow change formControl value from this what user sees on the screen.

Comment: @wantToBeAProgrammer you can use `.patchValue`? For updating formControl value.